# Delete cache for a single tooltip on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [BeautyTips plugin](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) for tooltips on my website.

I am caching all ajax content that goes into my tooltips. What I want to do is delete a cache for a single element after a click action.

So:

```
$("#SomeId").click(function(){
    /// now clear a tooltip cache but of only single tooltipped element. how to do it?
});
```

Comment: Need more details. How are you caching the content?

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall By setting ajaxCache option to true. Look here: http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/jquery.bt.js and scroll down to the bottom. There is a list of options.

Comment: I see... They've implemented their own cache storage which stores the data in the `body` element. It does seem to cache per url, and not per tooltip so you can only clear it for a specific url.

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall Could you help me out with some code example how to do it? I am not a JavaScript expert and I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an avid user of BeautyTips, but what I could see from the [source code](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/jquery.bt.js) is that the content cache is stored per url in the `body` element with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in the following format: `btCache-urlwithoutdots`

So removing cached content should be doable with the following line of code:

```
$(document.body).removeData("btCache-wwwexamplecom/foo/bar");
```

Note that I have not been able to test it out so I can't promise it will work.

Comment: @Richard, nice! It was a shot in the dark so I'm happy I hit the target :)